# Extract a specific link between <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-chrome-extension

I would like to extract a specific link (zip file) between two  tags  as below:

```
    <script>

    AAA:'https://url/*.zip'
    BBB:'https://url/*.avi'
    CCC:'https://url/*.mp4'

    </script>
```

I've tried with that but it doesn't work:

```
var links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("script[AAA:'https://url/*.zip']"); alert(links);
```

Normally I use querySelectorAll and that works with all other tags, but not here.. So i need here to extract https://url/*.zip link  and show it with an standard alert() box, Thanks!

Comment: The script is invalid and you're using an attribute selector for a tag with no attributes.

Comment: i'm new into javascript .. any help ?

Comment: Please explain to us the full scope of your question, as what you're asking right now doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Stop harassing the OP. Extracting variables from an inert page script is a common task for extensions or userscripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the values from the script element's text just like you would do it from a string:

```
function extractor(names) {
  const r = new RegExp(names.map(n => `\\b(${n}):\\s*'(.*?)'`).join('|'), 'g');
  for (const script of document.getElementsByTagName('script')) {
    const text = script.textContent;
    let match = r.exec(text);
    if (match) {
      const vars = {};
      do {
        const [/*source*/, name, value] = match;
        vars[name] = value;
        match = r.exec(text);
      } while (match);
      return vars; 
    }
  }  
}
```

When using in an extension popup to extract from the web page we need a helper function that runs the code as a content script:

```
function extractPageScriptVars(names) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: '(() => (' + extractor + ')(' + JSON.stringify(names) + '))()',
    }, ([vars]) => resolve(vars));
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
(async () => {
  const vars = await extractPageScriptVars(['AAA', 'BBB']);
  alert(JSON.stringify(vars, null, '  '));
})();
```

In case the script contains a valid JSON/JS object you can find its start/end indexes and extract the entire declaration string, then parse it with JSON.parse that produces an object/array, which you can use directly.

Comment: Worked Perfectly in chrome console Thank you! any idea how i can get it working with a minimum chrome extension ?

Comment: This is my actual working extension files: https://gist.github.com/NetviperZ/93d445c23b27052d2eff11aa3d07b3ad

when i put your script in popup.js nothing happen when i click on it

Comment: to be honest no, I am completely beginner, we can do it without even having the page popup.html? just with manifest.json and the script  file ?

Comment: 1) You need a popup to invoke chrome.downloads API. 2) See the updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much for all your time, i greatly appreciate your help!